# Data Loader keeps AUTOMATICALLY updating Opportunity name, even though I didn't want to

Tags: data-loader, data, loader

I'm using data loader to update a few hundred records (opportunities), I'm moving what account the opportunities are related to. In doing so, the opp names are being automatically updated/mirrored to the account they're now being related to, which I do **NOT** want it to do, I'd like them to keep their names, does this seem strange?

I checked for WFR thinking there was something there doing this, nadda, checked process builder as well, nothing there either even remotely close.

I've done a few different upload tests, one **with** mapping the opp name as a field, and one **without** mapping the opp name, in theory meaning both ways *should* be keeping the same name.

What in the world am I doing wrong?

Generic trigger interfaces for the Opportunity object.
See the OpportunityTriggerHandler and OpportunityUtils classes for implementation.

```
trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity(after delete, after insert, after undelete, after update,
before delete, before insert,           
before update) {

OpportunityTriggerHandler handler = new OpportunityTriggerHandler();

// before insert
if (Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert) {
    handler.OnBeforeInsert(Trigger.new);
}

// after insert
if (Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert) {
    handler.OnAfterInsert(Trigger.new, Trigger.newMap);
}

// before update
if (Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isUpdate) {
    handler.OnBeforeUpdate(Trigger.old, Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.new, Trigger.newMap);
}

// after update
if (Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate) {
    handler.OnAfterUpdate(Trigger.old, Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.new, Trigger.newMap);
}

// before delete
if (Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isDelete) {
    handler.OnBeforeDelete(Trigger.old, Trigger.oldMap);
}

// after delete
if (Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isDelete) {
    handler.OnAfterDelete(Trigger.old, Trigger.oldMap);
}

// after undelete
if (Trigger.isUnDelete) {
    handler.OnUndelete(Trigger.new);
}
```

}

The *OpportunityTriggerHandler* apex code should be below:

```
Implementation class for the generic Opportunity trigger methods.
public with sharing class OpportunityTriggerHandler {

public void OnBeforeInsert(Opportunity[] opportunities) {

}

public void OnAfterInsert(Opportunity[] opportunities, Map<Id, Opportunity>opportunitiesMap) {

}

public void OnBeforeUpdate(Opportunity[] oldOpportunities, Map<Id, Opportunity> oldOpportunitiesMap, 
                           Opportunity[] newOpportunities, Map<Id, Opportunity> newOpportunitiesMap) {
    OpportunityUtil.changeOpportunityAccount(oldOpportunitiesMap, newOpportunitiesMap);
    OpportunityUtil.updateContactRoleStage(newOpportunities);
}

public void OnAfterUpdate(Opportunity[] oldOpportunities, Map<Id, Opportunity> oldOpportunitiesMap, 
                          Opportunity[] newOpportunities, Map<Id, Opportunity> newOpportunitiesMap) {

}

public void OnBeforeDelete(Opportunity[] opportunities, Map<Id, Opportunity> opportunityMap) {

}

public void OnAfterDelete(Opportunity[] opportunities, Map<Id, Opportunity> opportunityMap) {

}

public void OnUndelete(Opportunity[] opportunities) {

}

}
```

Comment: You mentioned that you have checked WFR/PB but not code?

Comment: Verify if you have a trigger on Opportunity which most likely is generating the names as you see.

Comment: @Girbot are you referring to some sort of Apex stuff? If so, I haven't, but I certainly haven't added anything there as its over my head, and I'm the only one who would have ever added something as I'm the only "pseudo" admin. That being said others certainly have had their hands in the org before, there's always the possibility I wasn't aware of something and I'm down to check ANYTHING, this is driving me nuts!

Comment: We are limited to suggesting places to check as we don't know your org. The name changing pretty much has to be some form of automation. You can rule out Visualforce/buttons as you are using dataloader. If you have ruled out WFR/PB all I can think of left is triggers and/or managed packages...

Comment: so I guess one underlying question then is, this isn't normal/out-of-the-box functionality, correct?

Comment: there's a single trigger under the object manager portion of Opportunity named "OpportunityTrigger", I have a feeling though that this was some 'standard'/included trigger vs. someone having written it. The code for the trigger is only 45 lines, I can post here if you think that would help decipher what it does @Girbot

Comment: @DevinPearman - if you can post the relevant snippet from the trigger, that will help to identify, if that's what is causing this name change. Also please note, any trigger written on any object is always custom written and not included as part of any standard OOTB offering.

Comment: // before update
    if (Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isUpdate) {
        handler.OnBeforeUpdate(Trigger.old, Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.new, Trigger.newMap);
    }
    
    // after update
    if (Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate) {
        handler.OnAfterUpdate(Trigger.old, Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.new, Trigger.newMap);
    }

Comment: this was at the TOP of the apex trigger code

**
 * Generic trigger interfaces for the Opportunity object. 
 *
 * See the OpportunityTriggerHandler and OpportunityUtils classes for implementation.
 */

trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity(after delete, after insert, after undelete, after update, 
                                          before delete, before insert, before update) {

@JayantDas

Comment: sorry about the formatting...let me know if you want me to change it

Comment: @DevinPearman - Request you to [**edit**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/225415/edit) your post and add the *OpportunityTrigger* code details out there. Based on what you have mentioned in the comment, to be able to take a look, we would at least need to also see *OpportunityTriggerHandler* class as well.

Comment: @JayantDas I believe what you were looking for should now be added to my initial post, sorry again for any formatting stuff, I wrangled with it and it should look better now.

Comment: @DevinPearman Good that you were able to get past it, we all learn here. But now we would also need to view the *OpportunityUtil*'s *changeOpportunityAccount()* and *updateContactRoleStage()* methods. So if you can add that too in your post.